# Importing MobxAngularModule causes Ionic app compile fail

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobx

New to Ionic-Angular, once projectis stareted and MobxAngularModule is imported the errors below shows:

````
```[ng] Error: node_modules/mobx-angular/lib/mobx-reaction.directive.d.ts:9:26 - error TS2314: Generic 
type 'IReactionOptions' requires 1 type argument(s).```
````

from
:

````
    import { IReactionOptions } from 'mobx';
    import { MobxAutorunDirective } from './mobx-autorun.directive';
    export declare class MobxReactionDirective extends MobxAutorunDirective {
        protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
        protected viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;
        mobxReaction: any;
        mobxReactionOptions: **IReactionOptions**;
        constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef);
        autoDetect(view: any): void;
    }```

Error 2

    ```[ng] node_modules/mobx/dist/api/flow.d.ts(12,59): error TS2315: Type 'Generator' is not 
generic.```

How can this be fixed so I can keep practicing?
````

Comment: constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef); ... is missing brackets, should be ... constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {};

Comment: also try ... mobxReactionOptions: IReactionOptions<any>;

Comment: IReactioOptions<any> helps but still getting a bunch of errors ```[ng] node_modules/mobx/dist/types/observableset.d.ts(2,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'readonly'``` referring to export declare type ```IObservableSetInitialValues<T> = Set<T> | readonly T[];```

Comment: Thanks @danday74 , <any > helped , I have decided to redo the project from the scratch, I guess the template file has a lot of flaws. I have to slowly understand everything they did to replicate the project it without any issues